# Formula error after file save from network to local

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have issue with an Excel worksheet that contains the formula:

```
=Spline($D$9:$D$34,$J$9:$J$34,$D43)
```

Sheet works fine until I open this sheet on network drive and save it on local drive. Then this formula throws #NAME? error. Strange is, that error is gone when I click on line with formula to edit it and press enter (nothing changes in formula).

Have someone met similar issue?

I just found another information. Formula `spline` is defined in VBA module, not internal in Excel. It looks like. But issue is still here.

```
Function spline(periodcol As Range, ratecol As Range, x As Range)
Dim period_count As Integer
Dim rate_count As Integer
period_count = periodcol.Rows.Count
rate_count = ratecol.Rows.Count
If period_count <> rate_count Then
    spline = "Error: Range count does not match"
    GoTo endnow
End If


ReDim xin(period_count) As Single
ReDim yin(period_count) As Single
Dim c As Integer
For c = 1 To period_count
xin(c) = periodcol(c)
yin(c) = ratecol(c)
Next c
Dim n As Integer
Dim i, k As Integer
Dim p, qn, sig, un As Single
ReDim u(period_count - 1) As Single
ReDim yt(period_count) As Single
n = period_count
yt(1) = 0
u(1) = 0
For i = 2 To n - 1
    sig = (xin(i) - xin(i - 1)) / (xin(i + 1) - xin(i - 1))
    p = sig * yt(i - 1) + 2
    yt(i) = (sig - 1) / p
    u(i) = (yin(i + 1) - yin(i)) / (xin(i + 1) - xin(i)) - (yin(i) - yin(i - 1)) / (xin(i) - xin(i - 1))
    u(i) = (6 * u(i) / (xin(i + 1) - xin(i - 1)) - sig * u(i - 1)) / p

    Next i

qn = 0
un = 0
yt(n) = (un - qn * u(n - 1)) / (qn * yt(n - 1) + 1)
For k = n - 1 To 1 Step -1
    yt(k) = yt(k) * yt(k + 1) + u(k)
Next k
Dim klo, khi As Integer
Dim h, b, a As Single
klo = 1
khi = n
Do
k = khi - klo
If xin(k) > x Then
khi = k
Else
klo = k
End If
k = khi - klo
Loop While k > 1
h = xin(khi) - xin(klo)
a = (xin(khi) - x) / h
b = (x - xin(klo)) / h
y = a * yin(klo) + b * yin(khi) + ((a ^ 3 - a) * yt(klo) + (b ^ 3 - b) * yt(khi)) * (h ^ 2) / 6

spline = y
endnow:
End Function
```

Comment: In this moment, there is no UDF, just multiple formulas. I will be happy if i can solve this without VBA.

Comment: you could try to make a matrix-formular out of it. press `ctrl-shift-enter` instead of `enter` when you entered the formula

Comment: i dont see point in using `ctrl-shift-enter`. Formulas are working, till i try to resave sheet. So if i rewrite all formulas with `ctrl-shift-enter` you think it will help? It souns like some dark magic to me :/

Comment: because you defined a matrix within your formula. check out this explanation from MS
[Array formulars](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7#__learn_about_array)
In case you could also provide us sampledata so we're able to try it on our own =)

Comment: I figured out that `spline` function is defined in module and inserted code into main question. unfortunately `ctrl-shift-enter` not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

Application.Volatile

to your VBA code. Add this just below the Function statement to force a renewed calculation as soon as anything changes.